# Unable to I to display the list value in dropdown which I am passing as list from my java class in my JSP.My code works perfectly if I am using table

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am passing list from my java class in my JSP where I want to display the list value in dropdown. 
While debugging I checked that the list is containing desired values but not displaying in my JSP dropdown. 
Though the values are coming if I am displaying in Table form.

Please, tell me where I am going wrong and how can I make my code to work?

**Java Code:**

```
    // add the event list to the model
    theModel.addAttribute("event", theEvents);
    return "fundContributionCollectionListPage";
```

**JSP Code:**

```
    <select name="eventSelected">
    <c:forEach var="tempEvents" items="${event}">
      <option value="tempEvents.eventName">${tempEvents.eventName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Comment: change to `<c:forEach var="tempEvents" items="${event}">` **not** events

Comment: Thanks Scary. But, it was just typo by mistake while copy pasting here. I gave it as event and its not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Please show the code that **is** working

Comment: @Scary.. Thank you so much. The code is working now. I missed to add the jstl tag lib in my page where the dropdown was whereas I included the tag in my another jsp where I was getting the value in table.